# MouseAdapter methods - why `mouseDragged`, `mouseMoved` and `mouseWheelMoved` included?

Tags: java, swing, mouse-listeners, mousemotionevent

My goal was to simplify this code (all works fine):

```
package test;

import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import javax.swing.JWindow;

public class A extends JWindow implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {

    public A() {
        addMouseListener(A.this);
        addMouseMotionListener(A.this);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        //This method is being used, working fine
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        //This method is being used, working fine
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    }
}
```

But if I decide to use `MouseAdapter` like this:

```
addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        transferFocusBackward();
        //This method is being used, working fine
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        //This method is being used, not working anymore
    }
});
```

`mouseDragged` receiving no events. But if I add `MouseMotionListener` like this:

```
addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        //This method is being used, working fine
    }
});

addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        //This method is being used, working fine
    }
});
```

Then everything backs to normal. So my question is - what is the purpose of `mouseDragged`, `mouseMoved` and `mouseWheelMoved` methods in `MouseAdapter` class if they do not work?

Comment: You have to add your `MouseAdapter` using `addMouseMotionListener` if you want it to listen for mouse motion events.

Comment: Wait... what? I didn't realize they changed this in Java 6, as I'm still stuck using Java 5 where `MouseAdapter` *only* implements `MouseListener`. Next thing you'll tell me is that they improved `SwingWorker`. Ha, yeah right.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK, I think I understand now: in `MouseAdapter` class documentation it is said that "Create a listener object using the extended class and then register it with a component using the component's `addMouseListener`, `addMouseMotionListener`, `addMouseWheelListener` methods". So now it looks like:

```
private class MouseListeners extends MouseAdapter {

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        //This method is being used, working fine
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        //This method is being used, working fine
    }
}
```

and then:

```
MouseListeners listeners = new MouseListeners();   
addMouseListener(listeners);
addMouseMotionListener(listeners);
```

Now everything is OK.

Comment: +1 interesting progress:-), second time of this week I can here something like as == I read docs